# Email confirmation link using office 365 in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, exchangewebservices, asp.net-identity-2

I would like to send an email confirmation link to a user's email address after they have registered using ASP.NET Identity 2.2. Has anyone implemented it by using office 365 exchange online? Almost all material i can find uses sendgrid which I don't want to use since we already have office 365. I am not sure but I think it's by the use of Exchange Web Services. Kindly assist me with some sample code to get me started.Thanks.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster, kindly share a link of the appropriate resource. I can,t seem to find one that deals exactly with sending the email activation link via office 365 .

Comment: It's as simple as putting two and two together. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity for an `IIdentityMessageService` to send messages for registration and password recovery, and in that service, use the SMTP code shown in the duplicate.